# Sort by second field if the first field is null

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

How to convert this in C# linq/lambda query

```
select *
from meetings
order by ISNULL(ActualStartDate, StartDate) desc
```

so far I tried this but seems like it doesn't work:

```
meetings.OrderByDescending(m => m.ActualStartDate ?? m.StartDate);
```

UPDATE:

Actually this is correct. The problem is on the listview that shows the item. Apologies.

Actually my real problem is when both ActualStartDate and StartDate is null and I want it to show last. But thats a separate question I guess.

Comment: "seems like it doesn't work" tells us nothing about what's going wrong. A compile-time error? Unsorted data? Something else? *Please* think carefully when you post and provide all appropriate context.

Comment: I mean it does not sort the way I expecting. Just tested it.

Comment: Well how *does* it sort? And are you *actually* just calling that as a statement? (My answer explains that just calling `OrderByDescending` won't change anything - you need to use the return value.)

Comment: Do you materialize the result of sorting before testing/debugging?

Comment: And is this LINQ to SQL? EF? Something else? What is your input, what's the actual output, and what's the expected output? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Well, seems like it only sorts the m.StartDate even though the ActualStartDate has value!!.. By the way im using EF and the 'meetings' is IEnumerable<T> . Weird I have to scratch my eyes.

Comment: @lincx: If the type of `meetings` is `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IQueryable<T>` then you're using LINQ to Objects to do the ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
var sorted =  meetings.OrderByDescending(m => m.ActualStartDate ?? m.StartDate);
```

Note that calling the method won't change `meetings` - you need to use the return value which will be a sorted sequence of results. (This is in line with how LINQ works in general.)

If that still doesn't work, and assuming this is LINQ to SQL or something similar, you should look at the generated SQL to work out what's going on... then you can try to adjust your query appropriately.

Comment: @lincx: Well that's the problem with not giving nearly enough information in the question - when your post contains an error which isn't the *real* error, and you won't tell us what the real error is, how are we meant to help you? I've identified *two* potential problems in the code you've provided... without more information, I can't help any further.

Comment: Actually, it's the listview (Im using kendo mobile listview) that has the problem in displaying the sorted items and I just thought its the linq query.

Comment: Actually my real problem is when both ActualStartDate and StartDate is null and I want it to show last. But thats a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Others answers are correct, but you can use this way also.

```
 var meetings = meetings.OrderByDescending(p => p.ActualStartDate.HasValue)
                .ThenBy(p => p.StartDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "m." for the StartDate:

```
meetings.OrderByDescending(m => m.ActualStartDate ?? m.StartDate);
```

Comment: Do this as @John Skeet has suggested several times: meetings = meetings.OrderByDescending(m => m.ActualStartDate ?? m.StartDate);